# Is it possible to migrate my auth from Google to StackExchange ID?

Tags: support, openid

I'd like to move away from using my Google login for authentication but this is the mechanism I use to auth all of the StackExchange sites I participate in. I already created a StackExchange account with the same name but see no way to migrate accounts to it. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

Use the "my logins" link from your profile and add your Stack Exchange sign-in. That should do it.